# Create 'dynamic' images using JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've a form with 2 fields. How to create a new image with the values from these 2 fields in the query part of the "src" URL upon form submission?

Comment: You mean you want to fill in a url in one field then create a new image in the document using that url as the src parameter for the image?

Comment: @Marc B - yes, however path will be predefined (http://domain.com/images/img.png) and only query string should be "generated", so the whole URL will look like that: http://domain.com/images/img.png?field1value=foo&field2value=bar

Comment: ok, so I think I got it right. check my answer, it should be it. unless you don't want the jQuery solution, but that can be easily modified to basic javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example (using jQuery):

```
    <form id="myform">
        <input type="text" value="" id="input1">
        <input type="text" value="" id="input2">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <img id="image" src="http://mydomain.com/empty.gif" />
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myform").submit(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var val1 = $("#input1").val();
            var val1 = $("#input2").val();
            $("#image").attr("src", "http://mydomain.com/image?val1="+val1+"&val2="+val2);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

change mydomain.com to you host or relative path.